# Why does self.SwipeDirection work if the property is called swipeDirection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, naming-conventions

I have a simple ViewController derived from UIViewController to which I have added an enum property swipeDirection. In the code I normally refer to it as self.swipeDirection but in one instance I notice that I have mistakenly typed self.SwipeDirection.

If I jump to Definition I get the right variable and the code compiles and runs correctly so I  am sure that the correct variable is being used.

.h file

```
enum EScrollDirection
{
    E_SCROLL_DIRECTION_NONE = 0,
    E_SCROLL_DIRECTION_LEFT,
    E_SCROLL_DIRECTION_RIGHT,
    E_SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP,
    E_SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN
};
typedef enum EScrollDirection EScrollDirection;
@interface ProcessingViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, assign)EScrollDirection swipeDirection;
@end
```

.m file

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    CGPoint offset = self.graphScrollView.contentOffset;
    self.SwipeDirection = [self getScrollDirection:self.previousTouchPoint endPoint:self.graphScrollView.contentOffset];
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory all properties are compiled into a setter method call with the following rule by default - setter name for `property` is `setProperty:` (note 1st letter of property name becoming uppercase). So both the following lines of code

```
self.SwipeDirection = ...
self.swipeDirection = ...
```

are compiled to the existing setter method

```
[self.setSwipeDirection:...]
```

and so equivalent from compiler point of view.

Note - the same does not work for (default) getter method and the following line will not compile:

```
NSLog(@"%d", self.SwipeDirection);
```

Comment: thank you. I knew that the setters where named that way but never imagined that self.SwipeDirection was converted to the setter method before the syntax was checked. It seems wrong to me! Anyway thank you for the quick and precise answer.